# What are the differences between torch.jit.trace and torch.jit.script in torchscript?

Tags: pytorch, jit, torchscript

Torchscript provides torch.jit.trace and torch.jit.script to convert pytorch code from eager mode to script model. From the documentation, I can understand torch.jit.trace cannot handle control flows and other data structures present in the python. Hence torch.jit.script was developed to overcome the problems in torch.jit.trace.

**But it looks like torch.jit.script works for all the cases, then why do we need torch.jit.trace?**

Please help me understand the difference between these two methods

Answer (score 4):

If `torch.jit.script` works for your code, then that's all you should need. Code that uses dynamic behavior such as polymorphism isn't supported by the compiler `torch.jit.script` uses, so for cases like that, you would need to use `torch.jit.trace`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a deep dive into differences between the two which outlines when the "default recommended" `jit.script` is worse than `jit.trace`
https://ppwwyyxx.com/blog/2022/TorchScript-Tracing-vs-Scripting/